# How do I repair relationship with Client after we had a misunderstanding over work availability? (Reposted in freelance, can't delete here)

Tags: communication, contractors, remote-work

I've reposted this into freelance stack exchange as this is related to a freelance contractor. I'm unable to delete it from here, but I welcome your thoughts and opinions.

My client sends me a message out of the blue saying "we didn't know you were going away. We've been sending you new prospects and need to know when you're back."

Me: I'm working as usual, but remotely. May I please ask what caused this confusion/miscommunication that I'm away and unavailable?

Client: Loooong message explaining that she saw a photo of me overseas and it's unusual for people to be working overseas so assumed I'm away. Can you let us know next step you plan to work remotely so the assistant doesn't get anxious.

Me: ah, I see. Thanks for explaining. I can inform next time I'm planning to work remotely. This was unnecessary in hindsight but I went on to share how this made me feel, as this client is all about empathy and support & frequently expect me to honour when they share - I feel a bit confused and sense a lack of trust after working for a year and fulfilling all my agreements because I've given no reason to doubt my work integrity. I'd of course inform well in advance if I have holidays planned as well as organise a backup support.

I'm a contractor and work for this boss 2 days of the week and 15-min email checks on other days.

My bad assuming I could work remotely but since it didn't affect anyone in any way, I didn't see value in having to inform etc., I was still working Australia hours. Their policy didn't say anything about working remotely either.

We have a discussion scheduled next week. What's the best approach to put this misunderstanding to rest as I have said that I'll follow their new policies to inform when working remotely? I'm not sure what else needs to be reassured to get back to healthy terms.

Comment: Okay. What's your actual question that you'd like help with, remembering that we can't control how other people think and act?

Comment: What does your contract say with respect to working location? Are you to be working from home?

Comment: My question is - how can I professionally and calmly communicate to her that we could've avoided this issue by asking me a question instead of assuming based on a social media photo! I'm also wondering if they treat everyone like this or just me, probably triggered by the assistant complaining to the boss. Their message straight up was sarcastic "we somehow missed you were away"

Comment: I follow all our agreements to the t. There's nothing about remote work as of now. She has just created a policy on the go that I need to keep her assistant informed next time I travel & work remotely so the assistant doesn't get "anxious". To which, I agreed and said, sure, I can do that.

Comment: I don't hear anything resembling micromanagement in this post. Wanting to know when employees are available is ENTIRELY legitimate. Your failure to communicate, on the other hand....

Comment: Hi Keshlam, I'm a contractor who doesn't work from office. I usually work from home, or if I'm travelling remotely.

Comment: If you are freelance then and don't need to attend an office, you can work where ever you see fit assuming it doesn't impact the client (timezones etc). I would change the word 'boss' for client as boss suggests you are in an employed arrangement.

Comment: @DavidLindon Where you are able to work will depend on exactly what is in the contract. There are different types of "freelancing".

Comment: @GregoryCurrie that would become more of a contract employee. There is no country tag here so obviously these definitions vary by country.

Comment: @DavidLindon The OP mentions Australia, where there are either employees, or contractors. Regardless, whatever is in the contract is what matters. An employee (or contractor) isn't able to simply do things as they see fit because they don't think it impacts the client, they are obliged to follow the contract they have signed regardless.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie In the UK, there is a huge difference between an independent contractor and a contractor that works similar to an employee. A term that you need the employer's permission to work from abroad may mean you are not an independent contractor and may have huge tax implications.

Comment: Tax implications for both you and your employer, and likely visa implications too.

Comment: @gnasher729 No doubt about that. I'm not suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie the OP mentions Australian hours, they could be a remote working working that timezone so we will need clarification.

Comment: Thank you all. This is an independent or freelance contractor position, they assign prospects and I work with them directly, and I have a supervisor to reach out to if I need help or advise, and was also under supervision for the first few prospects. It's a very confusing structure & I'm moving away to a full-time job as soon as I find one.

Comment: I understand the tax implications for the company and myself.. this was 2 days during a week when I was travelling to another country. As they haven't specified in the agreement or contract, this seems to have been a miss from both sides. I don't plan to work remotely for a long duration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you've already agreed to inform your boss next time you plan to work (more) remotely, I don't feel there is much that needs to be done.

Your contract almost certainly indicates that you are obliged to follow policies and procedures during your engagement. If there is a new policy indicating you must inform, this is a no-brainer.

It's important to keep in mind that even if you have been trusted, and performed well, there may have been many other contractors in the past which have not done so. So there may be a history you are not aware of.

My recommendation is to give your boss a little slack in this regard. It's possible they may feel a little foolish. I think you've said all that you need to say on the matter.

Comment: Thank you Gregory. If they want to talk more, I'll stick to this point and reassure that I will follow all policies where it's been shared with me. If something hasn't been told, how would I know if that expectation!! I also understand sometimes they can't predict and add everything into the policy

Comment: Is it not some form of "weird/toxic" behaviour to jump to conclusions based on a personal photo they have no right to use in a professional context? (Maybe this happened in the past with someone else, not sure, but it still is so stupid to assume instead of just ask the employee!)

Comment: @corporateinnocence I don't know how they got the photo, but assuming they came across it by some sort of innocent means, I don't think it's incredibly strange for someone to have the mindset "at a beach, they must be on holiday!". Even it was a little strange, I don't think you should approach the situation any differently.

Comment: Thank you for that perspective. I'll lay my thoughts about judging their behaviour to rest and focus on the issue they raised, the details I provided and asking if there's anything else.

Comment: One thing, it's good to get an acknowledgement from your boss that they understand and have communicated the info to anyone else who needs to know.  At my last job I told my boss I'd be a little late (in by 9am rather than 7:30am).  Which is fine and accepted.  I came in before 9am and was seated at my desk when my boss's boss came in to check, because apparently someone had mentioned to him I was out.  And while I'm talking to him, accounting calls to check on me!  Apparently my boss forgot to pass on the word that I was out, and he was also late in that day.

Comment: Ooh, must've been so confusing for you DaveG after you did your bit and informed the boss.

Answer (score 3):

You screwed up. Never post your vacation plans or photos on social media.

> My bad assuming I could work remotely but since it didn't affect
> anyone in any way, I didn't see value in having to inform etc., I was
> still working Australia hours.

If your employer thinks you're working overseas for long periods of time, they may use that as a reason to reduce your pay somehow, since employers believe they have more leverage over overseas employees/contractors. They'll call such a reduction an adjustment in cost of living.

But there may also be other reasons also, for instance, if you're dealing with medical information or sensitive information. There may be legal reasons or security reasons they'd want you working on Australian soil only.

> She wants to chat to see how thus could've been avoided

Perhaps, they could hire you as a onsite full-time employee, or create an on-call schedule for you. For instance, I know an Emergency Room nurse. Her contract requires her to be 30 minutes away from her hospital and completely sober and available when she's on call, but she's also paid a lot of money for those extra on call hours (even when she ends up not working).

Basically, since your client is probably thinking of ways to reduce your pay, you should be thinking of reasons to increase your pay in exchange for the extra Service Level Agreement conditions she wants to place on you.

But now that I'm thinking about it, you may want to ask this question on https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ instead. If you keep this question posted on Workplace, you will get an analysis from the perspective of employees, not from the perspective of a freelance contractor who's only working 2 days a week for a particular client.

For instance, if you're working for multiple clients, and if your traveling is work related. Personally, I would not feel comfortable sharing such information with my other clients unless it directly impacted my work for them.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. It's great to hear the perspective on thinking about pay increase for the more demands they place on us. I'm planning to leave this client as soon as I get another full time job, hopefully soon.

Comment: How do I move it to freelance? Do I have to delete it here and repost it? Thank you so much.

Comment: @corporateinnocence, I'm not sure, but whether it gets moved, or you repost it, I recommend you change the title to "Micromanaging client assumes I'm out of office after looking at a travel pic". Honestly, you may just want to just repost it. This way, you can modify the question further and the current answers won't taint the other answers you're going to get.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks a ton! Both your answers have been really good though and very supportive in approaching the discussion she wants to have.

Comment: @corporateinnocence, One more thing. Given that you've already agreed to inform your boss next time you plan to work abroad, know that it's perfectly fine to tell her that you've changed your mind. There is a book called "When I Say No I Feel Guilty" by Manuel J. Smith that talks about how you can make such requests assertively.